# Find all rows whose column name contains a specific string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as shown below.It has 3 columns with names "TTN_163_2.5_-40 ","TTN_163_2.7_-40" and " TTN_163_3.6_-40".

I need to select all rows whose column name contains '2.5','3.6','2.7'.

I have some column names which contains 1.6,1.62 and 1.656.I need to select
these separately.when I am writing `df_psrr_funct_1V6.filter(regex='1\.6|^xvalues$')` I am geting all rows corresponds to 1.6 ,1.65 and 1.62 .I don't want this .May I know how to select uniquely.

I used this method (df_psrr_funct = df_psrr_funct.filter(regex='2.5'))but it is not capturing 1st column(xvalues)

Sample dataframe

```
xvalues TTN_163_2.5_-40     TTN_163_2.7_-40   TTN_163_3.6_-40   
23.0279  -58.7591            -58.5892           -60.0966    
30.5284  -58.6903             -57.3153          -59.9111
```

Please the image my dataframe

[image]
May I know how to do this

Comment: If it only has those four columns, then why not `df_psrr_funct = df_psrr_funct[["xvalues","TTN_163_2.5_-40"]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand regex with `|` for `or`, `^` is for start string, `$` is for end string for extract column name `xvalues` and avoid extract colums names with substrings like `xvalues 1` or `aaa xvalues`:

```
df_psrr_funct = df_psrr_funct.filter(regex='2\.5|^xvalues$')
print (df_psrr_funct)
   xvalues  TTN_163_2.5_-40
0  23.0279         -58.7591
1  30.5284         -58.6903
```

EDIT: If need values between `_` use:

```
print (df_psrr_funct)
   xvalues  TTN_163_1.6_-40  TTN_163_1.62_-40  TTN_163_1.656_-40
0  23.0279         -58.7591          -58.5892           -60.0966
1  30.5284         -58.6903          -57.3153           -59.9111

df_psrr_funct = df_psrr_funct.filter(regex='_1\.6_|^xvalues$')
print (df_psrr_funct)
   xvalues  TTN_163_1.6_-40
0  23.0279         -58.7591
1  30.5284         -58.6903
```

Answer (score 1):

using  regex for this doesnt make any sense... just do

```
columns_with_2point5 = [c for c in df.columns if "2.5" in c]
only_cool_cols = df[['xvalues'] + columns_with_2point5]
```

dont overcomplicate it ...

if you dont need the first column you can just use `filter` with `like` instead of using one of the regex solutions (see first comment from @BeRT2me)

Comment: That list comprehension is essentially equivalent to `df.filter(like='2.5')`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
df_psrr_funct.filter(regex = '^\D+$|2.5')

   xvalues  TTN_163_2.5_-40
0  23.0279  -58.7591
1  30.5284  -58.6903
```

Comment: Do keep in mind, `.` is the regex wildcard, so if you want a literal `.`, you must escape it: `\.`

Comment: I have some column names which contains 1.6,1.62 and 1.656.I need to select these separately.when I am writing df_psrr_funct_1V6.filter(regex='1\.6|^xvalues$') I am geting all rows corresponds to 1.6 ,1.65 and 1.62 .I don't want this .May I know how to select uniquely

Comment: @Hari, can you share full columns names, without looking at the pattern, difficult to code a regex

Comment: I don't think it is possible .I have 829 columns.